ChartIq@8.3.0 compatibility with Angular version 16
I'm trying to install ChartIq@8.3.0 in Angular@16, but I got errors when building components

'cq-dialog' is not a known element
'cq-side-panel' is not a known element:
'cq-abstract-marker' is not a known element:

It was working before upgrading Angular@10 to Angular@17
Are these errors related to version compatibility?
